# How solved the sintax to concat an element HTML?

Tags: reactjs

I have a code to render my value

```
<div >{`${t('single:yes')}: ${value}`}</div>
```

but i need to put a span between the value, for example:

```
<div >{`${t('single:yes')}:<span> ${value}<span>`}</div>
```

but dont work, what is the wrong?

Comment: Can you show us code from what you've already tried?

Comment: @Green-Avocado its my try <div >{`${t('single:yes')}:<span> ${value}<span>`}</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u want the code show like this?
before

```
<div >{`${t('single:yes')}:<span> ${value}<span>`}</div>
```

after

```
<div >{t('single:yes')}:<span> {value}</span></div>
```